# SQL Server SubSelect syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to execute a subselect query but it is giving me an error, I am not sure if I can do this kind of logic.

```
SELECT (SELECT SERV_ACCT, ACCOUNT, SERV_ADDRESS
FROM tblAPSData

JOIN tblMEP_Meters
ON tblMEP_Meters.ServiceAccount = tblAPSData.SERV_ACCT

WHERE SERV_Acct = ServiceAccount
AND INV_DATE > DATEADD(month, -6, getdate())
GROUP BY SERV_ACCT, ACCOUNT, SERV_ADDRESS
HAVING count(SERV_ACCT) = 1) AS AccountMeter

FROM tblMEP_Customers
```

THIS IS THE ERROR MESSAGE:
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 48
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I have also this code which compiles without any problems, I am using the same logic but don't know why it is not working. 
This code works when I run it:

```
SELECT SiteName = tblMEP_Sites.Name, BillingMonth = DateTimeStamp,
    ElectricConsumption = (SELECT SUM(Consumption)
    FROM tblMEP_Meters (nolock)
    JOIN tblMEP_MonthlyData (nolock)
    ON MeterID = tblMEP_Meters.ID
    WHERE SiteID = tblMEP_Sites.ID
    AND Type = 1
    AND BillingMonth = DATEADD(month, -6, getdate()))

    FROM tblMEP_Customers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reduce the code above

```
SELECT (SELECT SERV_ACCT, ACCOUNT, SERV_ADDRESS
FROM tblAPSData 
....
) AS AccountMeter

FROM tblMEP_Customers
```

, you can see that you are trying to select 3 fields `SERV_ACCT, ACCOUNT, SERV_ADDRESS` into `AccountMeter` which is not possible.
In your working second example only one value `SUM(Consumption)` is selected.
Since I cant detect any reference to tblMEP_Customers in your `SELECT ( ...) AS AccountMeter` query, I can not provide a solution for the desired output.